# Is it possible to put link in label of bubble chart in google charts?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am working on google charts and wondering if link can be put in label of bubbles in google bubble chart, gone through the [visualisation bubble chart api link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart) but could not find anything like this. I have tried allowHtml:true, but it is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

although html cannot be used for the bubble text
you can use the `'select'` event to perform the link action

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['ID', 'Life Expectancy', 'Fertility Rate', 'Region',     'Population'],
      ['CAN',    80.66,              1.67,      'North America',  33739900],
      ['DEU',    79.84,              1.36,      'Europe',         81902307],
      ['DNK',    78.6,               1.84,      'Europe',         5523095],
      ['EGY',    72.73,              2.78,      'Middle East',    79716203],
      ['GBR',    80.05,              2,         'Europe',         61801570],
      ['IRN',    72.49,              1.7,       'Middle East',    73137148],
      ['IRQ',    68.09,              4.77,      'Middle East',    31090763],
      ['ISR',    81.55,              2.96,      'Middle East',    7485600],
      ['RUS',    68.6,               1.54,      'Europe',         141850000],
      ['USA',    78.09,              2.05,      'North America',  307007000]
    ]);

    var options = {
      bubble: {
        textStyle: {
          fontSize: 11,
          color: '#0000EE',
          underline: true
        }
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
      var selection = chart.getSelection();
      if (selection.length > 0) {
        var url = 'https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=';
        var region = encodeURI(data.getValue(selection[0].row, 3));
        //window.open(url + region, '_blank');
        console.log(url + region);
      }
    });

    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```